# Possible Bug in JDBC?

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

I am currently facing a weird problem.
Whenever a user types something into the search bar that starts with an 's', the request crashes.
What you see next is a sample sql code generated by the search engine I programmed for this project.

```sql
    SELECT Profiles.ProfileID,Profiles.Nickname,Profiles.Email,Profiles.Status,Profiles.Role,Profiles.Credits, Profiles.Language,Profiles.Created,Profiles.Modified,Profiles.Cover,Profiles.Prename, Profiles.Lastname,Profiles.BirthDate,Profiles.Country,Profiles.City,Profiles.Phone,Profiles.Website, Profiles.Description, Profiles.Affair,Scores.AvgScore, coalesce(Scores.NumScore, 0) AS NumScore, coalesce(Scores.NumScorer, 0) AS NumScorer, (
    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM Likes
     JOIN Comments using(CommentID)
     WHERE Comments.ProfileID = Profiles.ProfileID)) NumLikes, (
(SELECT count(*)
  FROM Likes
 JOIN Comments using(CommentID)
  WHERE Comments.ProfileID = Profiles.ProfileID) /
  (SELECT coalesce(nullif(count(*), 0), 1)
 FROM Comments
 WHERE Comments.ProfileID = Profiles.ProfileID)) AvgLikes,                                                                                                             Movies.MovieID,                                                                                                        Movies.Caption,                                                                                                               Movies.Description,                                                                                                              Movies.Language,                                                                                                               Movies.Country,                                                                                                             Movies.City,                                                                                                             Movies.Kind,                                                                                                             Movies.Integration,  
    (SELECT cast(least(25 + 5.000000 * round((75 * ((0.500000 * SIZE/1024.0/1024.0 * 0.001250) + (0.500000 * Duration/60.0 * 0.050000))) / 5.000000), 100) AS signed int)
     FROM Streams
     WHERE MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND Tag = "main"
       AND ENCODING = "mp4") AS ChargeMain,

    (SELECT cast(least(25 + 10.000000 * round((75 * ((0.200000 * SIZE/1024.0/1024.0 * 0.001000) + (0.800000 * Duration/60.0 * 0.016667))) / 10.000000), 100) AS signed int)
     FROM Streams
     WHERE MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND Tag = "notes"
       AND ENCODING = "mp4") AS ChargeNotes,

    (SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0)
     FROM Views
     WHERE Views.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND Tag = "main") AS MainViews,

    (SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0)
     FROM Views
     WHERE Views.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND Tag = "notes") AS NotesViews,

    (SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0)
     FROM Views
     WHERE Views.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND Tag = "trailer") AS TrailerViews,

    (SELECT coalesce(greatest(
(SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0)
 FROM Views
 WHERE Views.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
   AND Tag = "trailer"),
 (SELECT coalesce(count(*), 0)
 FROM Views
  WHERE Views.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
 AND Tag = "main")), 0)) AS MaxMainTrailerViews,
    (SELECT avg(Score)
     FROM Scores
     WHERE Scores.MovieID = Movies.MovieID) AS Score,
    (SELECT coalesce(group_concat(cast(Score AS signed int)), "")
     FROM Scores
     WHERE Scores.MovieID = Movies.MovieID) AS Scores,                                                                                                          Movies.Cover,                                                                                                            Movies.Locked,                                                                                                             Movies.Created,                                                                                                           Movies.Modified,

    (SELECT coalesce(group_concat(name separator ','),"")
     FROM Tags
     JOIN TagLinks using(TagID)
     WHERE TagLinks.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
     ORDER BY name ASC) AS Tags,

    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM Purchases
     WHERE MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND ProfileID = %s
       AND TYPE = "main") AS PurchasedMain,

    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM Purchases
     WHERE MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND ProfileID = %s
       AND TYPE = "notes") AS PurchasedNotes,

    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM Watchlist
     WHERE MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND ProfileID = %s) AS Watchlist,

    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM Scores
     WHERE MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND ProfileID = %s) AS Rated,

    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM Comments
     WHERE MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND Deleted IS NULL) AS Comments,

    (SELECT sum(Duration)
     FROM Streams
     WHERE Streams.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
       AND Streams.Tag IN ("main",
                           "notes")
       AND Streams.ENCODING = "mp4") AS Runtime,

    (SELECT cast(count(*) AS signed int)
     FROM Movies
     JOIN Profiles ON Profiles.ProfileID = Movies.ProfileID
     WHERE ((Movies.Locked = 0
             AND
               (SELECT count(*)
                FROM Streams
                WHERE Streams.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
                  AND Streams.Status <> "ready") = 0
             AND Profiles.Status = "active")
            OR (%s = 1)
            OR (Movies.ProfileID = %s))
        AS Movies,

    (SELECT cast(ceil(count(*) / %s) AS signed int)
     FROM Movies
     JOIN Profiles using(ProfileID)
     WHERE ((Movies.Locked = 0
             AND
               (SELECT count(*)
                FROM Streams
                WHERE Streams.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
                  AND Streams.Status <> "ready") = 0
             AND Profiles.Status = "active")
            OR (%s = 1)
            OR (Movies.ProfileID = %s))
        AS Pages
    FROM Movies
    JOIN Profiles using(ProfileID)
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Movies.ProfileID AS ProfileID,
            avg(Scores.Score) AS AvgScore,
            count(*) AS NumScore,
            count(DISTINCT Scores.ProfileID) AS NumScorer
     FROM Scores
     JOIN Movies using(MovieID)
     GROUP BY Movies.ProfileID) AS Scores using(ProfileID)
    WHERE ((Movies.Locked = 0
            AND
              (SELECT count(*)
               FROM Streams
               WHERE Streams.MovieID = Movies.MovieID
                 AND Streams.Status <> "ready") = 0
            AND Profiles.Status = "active")
           OR (%s = 1)
           OR (Movies.ProfileID = %s))

    ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT %s,
                            %s
```

After countless hours of investigating and comparing possible user inputs with the generated sql code I finally nailed the problem down to some really strange behaviour of the JDBC driver which I consider a serious bug - yet I am not sure:

I spent another few hours trying to reproduce the problem with as less sql code as possible and ended up with the following:

```
SQL("""select * from Movies where "s" like "%s" and MovieID = {a} """)
.on('a -> 1).as(scalar[Long]*)
```

[SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).]

```
SQL("""select * from Movies where "s" like "%samuel" and MovieID = {a} """)
.on('a -> 1).as(scalar[Long]*)
```

[SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).]

```
SQL("""select * from Movies where "s" like "%flower" and MovieID = {a} """)
.on('a -> 1).as(scalar[Long]*)
```

[OK]

```
SQL("""select * from Movies where "s" like "%samuel" and MovieID = 1 """)
.on('a -> 1).as(scalar[Long]*)
```

[OK]

```
SQL("""select * from Movies where "s" like "%s" and MovieID = "{a}" """)
.on('a -> 1).as(scalar[Long]*)
```

[OK]

```
SQL("""select * from Movies where MovieID = {a} and "s" like "%s" """)
.on('a -> 1).as(scalar[Long]*)
```

[OK]

I believe to see a pattern here:
Under the exact condition that there is a %s sequence (quoted or unquoted) anywhere in a sql code, followed by a non quoted named parameter with arbitrary name and arbitrary distance
to the %s sequence, jdbc (or anorm) crashes. The crash seems to occur in JDBC, however its also possible that Anorm submits invalid values to JDBC.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: The queries are being executed against a mysql database server

Comment: Failing statement including sequence `%s` which is a format identifier, so it clashes with standard string formatting. Try to replace that in the statement by an Anorm placeholder and move the value in `.on(...)`, or use Anorm String interpolation (e.g. `... like ${"%s"} ...`). Passing as parameter is better in any way, driver with do the quoting of string properly.

Comment: Hmm to be all honest, I don't see the point in doing that. Scala string interpolation is done prior to the processing of Anorm or JDBC, so it won't affect what data those technologies will receive?

Comment: Wrong. Anorm interpolation is passing value as JDBC parameter, using the drive, as `.on`.

Comment: Related Anorm update: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/pull/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an enduring solution for the problem meanwhile. Since my sql generator needs to stay very flexible I somehow need a way to pass along sql fragments with their corresponding parameters without evaluating them right away. Instead the generator must be able to assemble and compose various sql fragments into bigger fragments at any time - just as he does now - but now with the acompanying, not yet evaluated parameters. I came up with this prototype:

```
DB.withConnection("betterdating") { implicit connection =>
  case class SqlFragment(Fragment: String, Args: NamedParameter*)

  val aa = SqlFragment("select MovieID from Movies")
  val bb = SqlFragment("join Profiles using(ProfileID)")
  val cc = SqlFragment("where Caption like \"%{a}\" and MovieID = {b}", 'a -> "s", 'b -> 5)

  // combine all fragments
  val v1 = SQL(Seq(aa, bb, cc).map(_.Fragment).mkString(" "))
            .on((aa.Args ++ bb.Args ++ cc.Args): _*)

  // better solution
  val v2 = Seq(aa, bb, cc).unzip(frag => (frag.Fragment, frag.Args)) match {
    case (frags, args) => SQL(frags.mkString(" ")).on(args.flatten: _*)
  }

  // works
  println(v1.as(scalar[Long].singleOpt))
  println(v2.as(scalar[Long].singleOpt))
}
```

It seems to work great! :-)

I then rewrote the last part of the freetext filter as follow:

```
// finally transform the expression
// list a single sql fragment
expressions.zipWithIndex.map { case (expr, index) =>
  s"""
    (concat(Movies.Caption, " ", Movies.Description, " ", Movies.Kind, " ", Profiles.Nickname, " ",
    (select coalesce(group_concat(Tags.Name), "") from Tags join TagLinks using (TagID)
    where TagLinks.MovieID = Movies.MovieID)) like "%{expr$index}%"))
  """ -> (s"expr$index" -> expr)
}.unzip match { case (frags, args) => SqlFragment(frags.mkString(" and "), args.flatten: _*)
```

What do you think?

Answer (score -1):

This is how it is being implemented right now:

```
  /**
   * This private helper method transforms a content filter string into an sql expression
   * for searching within movies, owners and kinds and tags.
   * @author Samuel Lörtscher
   */
  private def contentFilterToSql(value: String) = {
    // trim and clean and the parametric value from any possible anomalies
    // (those include strange spacing and non closed quotes)
    val cleaned = value.trim match {
      case trimmed if trimmed.count(_ == '"') % 2 != 0 =>
        if (trimmed.last == '"') trimmed.dropRight(1).trim
        else trimmed + '"'
      case trimmed =>
        trimmed
    };

    // transform the cleaned value into a list of expressions
    // (words between quotes are considered being one expression)
    // empty expressions between quotes are being removed
    // expressions will contain no quotes as they are being stripped during evaluation -
    // thus counter measures for sql injection should be obsolete
    // (we put an empty space at the end because it makes the lexer algorithm much
    // more efficient as it will not need to check for end of file in every iteration)
    val expressions = (cleaned + " ").foldLeft((List[String](), "", false)) { case ((list, expr, quoted), char) =>
      // perform the lexer operation for the current character
      if (char == ' ' && !quoted) (expr :: list, "", false)
      else if (char == '"') (expr :: list, "", !quoted)
      else (list, expr + char, quoted)
    }._1.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.trim)

    // finally transform the expression
    // list into a variable length sql condition statement
    expressions.map { expr =>
      s"""
        (concat(Movies.Caption, " ", Movies.Description, " ", Movies.Kind, " ", Profiles.Nickname, " ",
        (select coalesce(group_concat(Tags.Name), "")
        from Tags join TagLinks using (TagID) where TagLinks.MovieID = Movies.MovieID)) like "%$expr%")
      """
    }.mkString(" and ")
  }
```

Since the number of search expressions is variable, I cannot use Anorm arguments here. :-/

I found a simple solution now, but I am not exactly happy being forced to apply such crappy hacks. 
Since putting a %s character sequence seems to trigger the bug, I was looking for possibilities to submit the same semantical outcome without directly passing this character sequence. I finally ended up replacing **like "%$expr%"** by **like concat("%", "$expr%")**. Since concat is being evaluated by the MySql Server engine BEFORE "like", he will put the original pattern back together before processing it by "like" - and without the sequence %s ever being transmitted through the anorm, jdbc data processors.

```
// finally transform the expression
// list into a variable length sql condition statement
// (freaking concat("%", "$expr%")) is required due to a freaking bug in either anorm or JDBC
// which results into a crash when %s is anyway submitted)
expressions.map { expr =>
  s"""
    (concat(Movies.Caption, " ", Movies.Description, " ", Movies.Kind, " ", Profiles.Nickname, " ",
    (select coalesce(group_concat(Tags.Name), "")
    from Tags join TagLinks using (TagID) where TagLinks.MovieID = Movies.MovieID)) like concat("%", "$expr%"))
  """
}.mkString(" and ")
```

Comment: But you can use a variable number of parameter bindings.

Comment: This is not an answer. Edit your question if you want to add some code.

Comment: As said it's way better to pass string values as parameters instead of having them in the statement, have you tried it? Moreover, with multi-value parameter, Anorm supports that "number of search expressions is variable".